# Установить границы в numpy array

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

Я хотел бы провести серию экспериментов, добавляя некоторый шум к картинке (numpy array 28x28). Каждый элемент массива содержится в интервале [0,1]. Однако при добавлении шума (из интервала [-1,1]) элемент может "выпасть за интервал".

Есть ли какая-то функция для установления границ массива? Не записывая это через 2 цикла и оператор `if`.

Массив:

```
[0.75 0.24],
[0.04 0.99]
```

Шум:

```
[0.14 0.14],
[0.14 0.14]
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
[0.89 0.38],
[0.18 1.]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [np.clip()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html):

```
In [257]: a
Out[257]:
array([[0.75, 0.24],
       [0.04, 0.99]])

In [258]: noice
Out[258]:
array([[0.14, 0.14],
       [0.14, 0.14]])

In [259]: res = np.clip(a + noice, a_max=1, a_min=0)
```

результат:

```
In [260]: res
Out[260]:
array([[0.89, 0.38],
       [0.18, 1.  ]])
```